# Distributable application using portaudio and libsndfile

Tags: c, dll, linker, portaudio, libsndfile

I have written a small C program using portaudio and libsndfile which works only on my PC. In other systems it asks for libportaudio.dll and libsndfile.dll.I am linking with -lportaudio and -lsndfile.

I want to make this work everywhere(Windows) without asking for such things ?

What should i do to make this application (.exe) distributable ?

(I am using Code blocks and Mingw)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: libsndfile uses a LGPL licence I believe. You can't statically link LGPL code unless it has a static-link exception. PortAudio uses an MIT licence and you can (in theory) statically link it.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing `-static` to the compiler, to ask it to make the library references *static*, as opposed to dynamic. You can see if you've successfully made the binary statically linked by running `nm` on it.

Of course you must also make sure you don't violate any licenses by re-distributing the libraries in this fashion.

Comment: I tried that.. still not working... I even tried statically linking using -l portaudio.dll.a and -l libsndfile.dll.a and removed        -lportaudio -lsndfile, then it gives undefined references to the functions used.. Can you please provide some example compilation schemes ?